# While installing tensorflow in ubuntu for keras backend should I install it in virtual environment or main python files

Tags: keras

> iddharth@siddharth-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ source ./venv/bin/activate
>   (venv) siddharth@siddharth-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ python -c "import
>   tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
>   2020-06-07 13:40:24.858083: W
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could
>   not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory 2020-06-07
>   13:40:24.858216: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313]
>   failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303) 2020-06-07 13:40:24.858349:
>   I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel
>   driver does not appear to be running on this host
>   (siddharth-HP-EliteBook-8460p): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not
>   exist 2020-06-07 13:40:25.024713: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU
>   Frequency: 2593965000 Hz 2020-06-07 13:40:25.025838: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service
>   0x7f0574000b60 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee
>   that XLA will be used). Devices: 2020-06-07 13:40:25.025876: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor
>   device (0): Host, Default Version tf.Tensor(-1066.3622, shape=(),
>   dtype=float32)

Comment: You did not install CUDA + CuDNN, or the path towards them is not visible, hence the fallback on CPU.

Comment: What is the question here? Question title and body do not really match